# Ionic serve does not load angular js and ionic css

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new in this Ionic field. I created a new app in my localhost folder(C:\xampp\htdocs). When I go to "http://localhost/ionapp/www/" everything works fine but when I run the app from "ionic serve" command I get the blank page.
When I viewed the page source I found that ionic.css and ionic.bundle.js file are not loaded during ionic serve. And in the console I get the error like "angular is not defined". Can anyone please help me fix this?

Here is my index.html which should load css and js files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, it seems you're new around here. When asking questions like this it's mandatory to post code example on either Codepen/Plunker/JSfiddle, so that one can try to help you. Without it it's just a shot in the dark. And besides, to be honest, your question will receive negative points and in turn not being answered at all. Here's a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks @Nikola for reminding me that but I just created a new tabs(default) app using Ionic CLI and haven't changed a thing so that's a lot of code. Do I need to post all that code to Codepen/Plunker/JSfiddle? Besides as I mentioned the problem does not seems to be in my code. The code works fine when I use localhost/myapp/www but it does not work with "ionic serve" command. So the problem seems to be in my CLI so I thought the code will not help.

Comment: Do you have the latest cli installed? Btw, if it works in xampp, I would suspect that you may have some port blocking set up on your machine since ionic serve tries to start up and serve it on port 8100.

Comment: Yeah I just installed ionic today for the second time since I got the same problem at first. Port 8100 also runs without any problem but the only problem I got is the files in "myapp/www/lib/ionic" (specifically css/ionic.css and js/ionic.bundle.js) does not load which crashes the application.

Comment: @user3599349, can u post your `index.html` page, which should have the `js` and `css` script tags

Comment: @sameera207 I have included my `index.html`

Comment: try running the cmd prompt (if in windowds) as a adminstrator before running ionic serve, if you are in osx or LINUX! the use sudo ionic serve. May not do anything but worth a shot.

Comment: @JessPatton no luck with admin command prompt as well

Answer (score 0):

So it was not the issue with my ionic but with my browser. Turns out I was getting `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` in my console. So basically what I did was

1. Open cmd prompt as administrator.
2. Run the command `netsh winsock reset`.
3. Restart my computer.

I don't know how it happened but it solved all my problems.